# javaScript(angular) get the value of each elemnt

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

i've a question about getting id of each element. 
i've a listview, and when i click each element, i want to get the id of last row('myID'). *My problem is, i get always the same id(39) by every click*

Here is my angularJS code :

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

function ctrlGenel($scope) {
    $scope.call = function(){
      var getID = angular.element(document.querySelector('#myID'));
        alert(getID.html());
    }   
};
```

and my html looks like below :

```
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='ctrlGenel'>
    <div id='listview' ng-click='call()' class='listview'>
        <h3>Title 1</h3>
        <h4>Açıklama 1</h4>
        <p id='myID'>39</p>
    </div>

    <div id='listview' ng-click='call()' class='listview'>
        <h3>Title 2</h3>
        <h4>Açıklama 1</h4>
        <p id='myID'>40</p>
    </div>

    <div id='listview' ng-click='call()' class='listview'>
        <h3>Title 3</h3>
        <h4>Açıklama 1</h4>
        <p id='myID'>41</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a JSFiddle Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/aldimeola1122/40rx6xwt/

Can you please help me? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: don't use same ID for multiple elements. Ids should be unique. use class instead

Comment: yes,but i should use the same id, because they are created dynamicaly in a for loop.

Comment: append a index to id in a loop, like "myID"+index of loop

Comment: General rule of programming (and life) - IDs should always uniquely identify the thing in question. If they don't, you're likely doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

You can access your clicked dom element by using $event of ng-click.
You just have to call currentTarget on it like this $event.currentTarget in your controller.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);



  function ctrlGenel($scope) {
        $scope.call = function(event){
          var getID = angular.element(event.currentTarget.querySelector('.myClass'));
            alert(getID.html());
        }   
    };
```

Then in your html :

```
 <div ng-app='app' ng-controller='ctrlGenel'>
    <div id='listview' ng-click='call($event)' class='listview'>
         <h3>Title 1</h3>
         <h4>Açıklama 1</h4>
        <p class='myClass'>39</p>
    </div>

    <div id='listview' ng-click='call($event)' class='listview'>
     <h3>Title 2</h3>
     <h4>Açıklama 1</h4>
    <p  class='myClass'>40</p>
    </div>

    <div id='listview' ng-click='call($event)' class='listview'>
     <h3>Title 3</h3>
     <h4>Açıklama 1</h4>
    <p class='myClass'>41</p>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Notice that I am using class instead of id

Comment: @aldimeola1122 glad to have helped you :) please mark my response as answered thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do this:

```
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='ctrlGenel'>
<div id='listview' ng-click="call('myID')" class='listview'>
 <h3>Title 1</h3>
 <h4>Açıklama 1</h4>
 <p id='myID'>39</p>
</div>

<div id='listview' ng-click="call('myID1')" class='listview'>
<h3>Title 2</h3>
<h4>Açıklama 1</h4>
<p  id='myID1'>40</p>
</div>

<div id='listview' ng-click="call('myID2')" class='listview'>
<h3>Title 3</h3>
<h4>Açıklama 1</h4>
<p id='myID2'>41</p>
</div>
</div>
```

and your angular part

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

function ctrlGenel($scope) {
$scope.call = function(id){

  var getID = angular.element(document.querySelector('#'+id));
    alert(getID.html());
  } 
};
```